# Best glue to fix stripped frying pan lid knob?

Tags: kitchen

I have a frying pan with a metal lid.  The lid has a small threaded post sticking out of the top of it onto which a wooden knob is screwed.  The threads inside the knob have become stripped so the knob will no longer stay attached to the pan lid.

This would seem like a job for either Krazy Glue or Gorilla Glue if not for the high temperature that the fix will have to endure.  All of the glues that I find that boast a specific temperature rating do not seem appropriate to the task (pastes, ribbons, etc.). Many glues are described as "temperature resistant" or "can handle temperature changes", but I don't know what those phrases really mean.

One common high-temp substance is silicon sealer, but that isn't going to provide the strength I need for this job, right?

In short, what is the best glue to use on a frying pan lid/knob?

Comment: Wood knob will accommodate 450°F/233°C so if temperature ratings allow for that, you're good to go. BTW, you'll need some kind of material to fill gaps. Krazy won't fill gaps.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have a wood knob, I don't think there is huge amounts of heat. Use a steel-type epoxy like JB-Kwik. First clear any loose bits from the wood knob. Then mix a small amount and force a dab into the hole. Push and twist the knob into place. Any epoxy that leaves the hole and fills the flat gap will add to the strength. If any oozes out, you can wipe it away or cut it when it is slightly hardened. Leave everything motionless until the next day.

Answer (score 4):

get you a couple of thin wooden tooth picks. dip them in wood glue and jam them down into the stripped-out hole in the knob, and break them off flush with the backside of the knob. allow to dry, then screw the knob back down onto the threaded stub.

Comment: This, on the assumption the thread going into the knob is a screw, rather than a threaded bolt. It probably is the former, and hardly needs the glue.

Comment: This is an excellent idea.  It's certainly worth a try first (without the glue).  It isn't a threaded knob.  It's just some sort of hardwood that I supposes is particularly heat resistant.

Comment: woodworkers use the toothpick method all the time. sometimes if the hole is very badly stripped out, you'll press a glued dowel into it and redrill a new pilot hole. works well as long a you let the glue completely harden first.

Answer (score 3):

Two part epoxy resin will do a far better job. Clean out the hole, knock in some slivers of wood (toothpicks are my favourite), along with a little premixed adhesive, screw the knob back in. Use next day and for ever.

Comment: Do I need a particular epoxy that is particularly heat resistant, or will they all deal with 300+ degree heat?

Comment: The epoxy is hardly going to be there. The extra wood filling in the hole should do by itself.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my kettle's wooden knob a while ago.
I used normal white glue (not school glue which doesn't harden completely).

The knob was heavily carboned (burnt). It slid on and off the threaded post easily. I figured that I had nothing left to lose so I filled the burned hole with some white glue and set the lid on it upside down until the glue hardened. It took a day or so.

It's been over a year using my kettle many times a day, everyday, without a hitch.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off doing it differently. How it is right now, it fell apart for a reason; you're not solving the reason by just packing the hole. Instead I'd:

- Use a drill to extend the hole right the way through the knob
- Use a larger drill to create a recessed hole in the top of the knob
- Use a longer bolt and locking nut, that goes right the way through the knob, with the locking nut in the recessed hole

[image]

Comment: This won't work because there isn't enough of a post.  It only sticks up maybe 1/2", probably more like 3/8". - good idea under a different circumstance though. - I appreciate the diagram!

Comment: "use a longer bolt" - i.e. replacement of any existing post, but if you can find a nut that screws onto the existing post then see if you can drill a deeper recess into the knob. A picture of what you have would also help..

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the glue being exposed to high temperature, automotive stores sell high temperature glue designed to exist near an internal combustion engine when hot.